# How to order by C# list so that the duplicate items appear in the reverse order of their insertion

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

How to order by a list so that the duplicate items appear in the reverse order of their insertion (consider that I am not going to insert any items in the middle by using insert method of list)

Take following example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "A"));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "F"));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4, "G"));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "B"));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "C"));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "E"));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "D"));

        list=list.OrderBy(a=>a.Key).ToList();

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, A]
[2, B]
[2, C]
[3, F]
[3, E]
[3, D]
[4, G]
```

I want the order of duplicates in reverse order of insertion, e. g. F, E, D should appear as D, E, F.

I though orderByDescending would do the trick but that would also maintain the order of insertion.

Comment: you are ordering on the key, the keys are identical so it will not change the original order of those items.

Comment: what is your reverse point of view? natural reverse or your list's order

Comment: Insertion order into what? The list?

Comment: Are you sure about this requirement because this has a very specific meaning: *so that the duplicate items appear in the reverse order of their insertion.*?

Comment: Yea, that's exactly I am looking for. Can list index help me here somehow?

Comment: No, List has an Insert(index) method.  So the index will not reliably tell you the order items were inserted.

Comment: @Randeep Trevors answer will do the job.

Comment: @Randeep how do you plan on mitigating the issue where a list can have an item inserted into middle of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OrderBy is a stable sort, this means that Items cannot be differentiated remain in the same order. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2

This means that duplicate items will be remain in the order they were added so we can do this

```
list = list
        .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
        .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Reverse())
        .ToList();
```

So we group by the keys, unique items will have 1 item in the group, duplicates will have more than 1 item. The items in the groups will be in the same order as the source Enumerable, See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

So we can order by the keys of the groups and for each group we select its items in reverse order.

Also this works too

```
list = list
        .Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i })
        .OrderBy(_ => _.Item.Key)
        .ThenByDescending(_ => _.Index)
        .Select(_ => _.Item)
        .ToList();
```

This makes use of the [Select Override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that provides you the index of the item in the collection as well as the item

Comment: This will work provided nobody ever inserts a value into the List at a chosen index instead of the end.  Then index, and thus current order in the list, will not accurately reflect insertion order.  But I like this code :)

Comment: This has the same shortcoming as @user7396598. Also doing a `GroupBy` and not doing anything with each group is hacky.

Comment: There is a fine line between hacky and making use of the toolset, that version tows the line, I'll give you that. I've added a second version

Comment: @user7396598 Since a List has absolute no way of recording insertion order this is the best OP can hope for

Comment: @CodingYoshi this doesnt have the same short comings as that answer at all (no offence) that answer was ordering by value of the KVP if the insertion order of the list inserted F before D then it would fail. Mine assumes the order of the starting list is the order insertion (that is all we can do) and then uses that order and that it is retained when orderby cannot order it and then reverses it

Comment: @Dave That is because you edited your answer and it no longer has the shortcoming. Now it will work and now you are using `GroupBy` for a valid reason.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I didn't change the first bit of code, I just added the second

Comment: @Dave Yes I know. And that is the bit that does the trick. Good for  you.

Comment: @Dave Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list=list.OrderBy(a => a.Key).ThenBy(a => a.Value).ToList();
```

I believe this will give the results you are looking for.  But not the logical execution you have explained.

In order to order them by insertion, you need to track that info some how.  In your current code your order by knows nothing about when an item was added to the list, it only knows Key and Value.

You may do this with a custom object rather than a Key-Value Pair.

An object made up of a

```
List<kvp<int, kvp<int, string>>>
```

with it's own Add() method would work.  Use the outer int as your insert order.  Use your overwrite to Add() to grab the the current length of the list and increment your insert order before adding the new object, thus maintaining the correct sequence regardless of the index it is inserted at.

Comment: *duplicate items appear in the reverse order of their insertion*, NOT the reverse order of the values. You are doing it by values.

Comment: @CodingYoshi no kidding, that is specifically what the explanation says...

Comment: Yes but you are not answering the question, you are saying "this orders by value but not what you want OP". So you are not answering the question.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I also provided an answer to the question...He must know the insertion order and track it

Comment: Well people seem to be downvoting your answer so you may want to do something about it. I have not even downvoted it yet...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't double-checked the syntax yet, but ...

```
list
    .Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count), (item, insertOrder) => new { Item = item, InsertOrder = insertOrder })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item.Key)
    .ThenBy(x => x.InsertOrder)
    .Select(x => x.Item)
    .ToList();
```

What this does is create an `Enumerable.Range` to record the insertion order of each item, then it's a straightforward case of `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` to correctly order the items, then `Select` to remove the `InsertOrder` again.

As user7396598 quite correctly points out, the `IEnumerable` order of the list is not necessarily the order they were inserted.  However if you're using this in a known context where the items have been inserted without using specific indices, it should suffice.  If the context is not known, you'll need to expand the data you're capturing to include the insert order, possibly by creating your own collection class that records the insertion order and doesn't permit index insertion.

Hope this helps

Comment: Clever and probably the only solution which will satisfy the requirement in the question.

Comment: Not really.  This gets you an insert order based on the current index of each entry in the list.  List provides an Insert(index) method that will make these results incorrect.

Comment: @user7396598 Yes but you are creating other scenarios which the OP never asked for.

Comment: @CodingYoshi it's not a matter of asked for, it's the behavior of List undermining the expected outcome of the logic he is employing.